# Rendering React component from inside StencilJS component and mapping slot to props.children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web-component, stenciljs

I would like to wrap an existing React component inside a StencilJS component.

I have a kinda mvp thing working by calling ReactDom.render inside the StencilJS `componentDidRender` hook and after rendering moving the  into the react child element, however I'm wondering if there is a nicer way to achieve this.

I don't like that this requires two wrapper elements inside the host, and manually moving the slot into the React component feels pretty icky.

Example code - the existing react component I am trying to render here is a Bootstrap Alert from the react-bootstrap project, just as an example.

```
import {
    Component,
    ComponentInterface,
    Host,
    h,
    Element,
    Prop,
    Event,
} from '@stencil/core';
import { Alert, AlertProps } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

@Component({
    tag: 'my-alert',
    styleUrl: 'my-alert.css',
    shadow: false,
})
export class MyAlert implements ComponentInterface, AlertProps {
    @Element() el: HTMLElement;

    @Prop() bsPrefix?: string;
    @Prop() variant?:
        | 'primary'
        | 'secondary'
        | 'success'
        | 'danger'
        | 'warning'
        | 'info'
        | 'dark'
        | 'light';
    @Prop() dismissible?: boolean;
    @Prop() show?: boolean;
    @Event() onClose?: () => void;
    @Prop() closeLabel?: string;
    @Prop() transition?: React.ElementType;

    componentDidRender() {
        const wrapperEl = this.el.getElementsByClassName('alert-wrapper')[0];
        const slotEl = this.el.getElementsByClassName('slot-wrapper')[0];

        const alertProps: AlertProps = {
            variant: this.variant,
            dismissible: this.dismissible,
            show: this.show,
            onClose: this.onClose,
            closeLabel: this.closeLabel,
            transition: this.transition,
        };

        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(
                Alert,
                alertProps,
                React.createElement('div', { className: 'tmp-react-child-el-class-probs-should-be-a-guid-or-something' })
            ),
            wrapperEl
        );

        const reactChildEl = this.el.getElementsByClassName(
            'tmp-react-child-el-class-probs-should-be-a-guid-or-something'
        )[0];
        reactChildEl.appendChild(slotEl);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Host>
                <div class="alert-wrapper"></div>
                <div class="slot-wrapper">
                    <slot />
                </div>
            </Host>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple tips:

- You don't need the `wrapperEl`, you can just render your react component into the host element `this.el` instead.
- Since you're not using `shadow`, you can clone your component's slot content and use that as the react component's children.
- Instead of `this.el.getElementsByClassName('slot-wrapper')[0]` you can also use `this.el.querySelector('.slot-wrapper')`, or use an [element reference](https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx#getting-a-reference-to-a-dom-element).
- `onClose` shouldn't be used as a prop name because `on...` is also how event handlers are bound, e. g. if your component emits a `'click'` event, then you can bind a handler for it by setting an `onClick` handler on the component. You've decorated it as an event though but that doesn't work afaik.

---

Working example on codesandbox.io:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stencil-react-mv5p4?file=/src/components/my-alert/my-alert.tsx
(this will also work with respect to re-rendering)

```js
import {
  Component,
  ComponentInterface,
  Host,
  h,
  Element,
  Prop,
  Event,
} from '@stencil/core';
import { Alert, AlertProps } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-alert',
  shadow: false,
})
export class MyAlert implements ComponentInterface {
  @Element() host: HTMLMyAlertElement;

  @Prop() bsPrefix?: string;
  @Prop() variant?:
    | 'primary'
    | 'secondary'
    | 'success'
    | 'danger'
    | 'warning'
    | 'info'
    | 'dark'
    | 'light';
  @Prop() dismissible?: boolean;
  @Prop() show?: boolean;
  @Prop() closeHandler?: () => void;
  @Prop() closeLabel?: string;
  @Prop() transition?: React.ElementType;

  originalContent: any[];

  componentDidLoad() {
    // clone the original (slotted) content
    this.originalContent = Array.from(this.host.childNodes).map(node =>
      node.cloneNode(true),
    );

    this.componentDidUpdate();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const alertProps: AlertProps = {
      variant: this.variant,
      dismissible: this.dismissible,
      show: this.show,
      onClose: this.closeHandler,
      closeLabel: this.closeLabel,
      transition: this.transition,
      ref: el => el?.append(...this.originalContent), // content injected here
    };

    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Alert, alertProps), this.host);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <slot />
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
re: event naming, I did see the lint warnings about it but was trying to get it working using the exact same props interface exported from the existing react component - though I imagine this would be a good point to rename / tidy up some of those props and expose them differently!