# TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function in stenciljs

Tags: reactjs, npm, stenciljs

I trying to use multiselect-react-dropdown package inside my stencil project, but while rendering I'm getting this error, I found many solution for react but nothing really worked, Can anyone help do same in stenciljs.

```
import { Component, h, State } from '@stencil/core';
import { Multiselect } from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';


@Component({
    tag: 'ui-card',
    styleUrl: 'style.scss',
    shadow: true
})

export class UiCard {
    @State() state: any;

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            options: [{ name: 'Srigar', id: 1 }, { name: 'Sam', id: 2 }]
        };
    }

    onSelect(selectedList, selectedItem) {
        console.log(selectedItem)
        console.log(selectedList)
    }

    onRemove(selectedList, removedItem) {
        console.log(selectedList)
        console.log(removedItem)
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>
            <Multiselect
                options={this.state.options}
                selectedValues={this.state.selectedValue}
                onSelect={this.onSelect}
                onRemove={this.onRemove}
            />
        </div>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

StencilJS is not related to React.
Indeed they both are using `JSX/TSX` as a markup language, but React uses it's own `React` implementation of it, while StencilJS uses `h` jsxFactory.
As you may know, JSX is transpired to the regular function calls like `createElement` which return a Virtual DOM object to render.
So, to render react Virtual DOM object to the page you need to call `ReactDOM.render()`, meanwhile Stencil compiles it to the web-components.
Despite a lot of common things like `JSX`, `props/state` and other - React and StencilJS are completely different tools.

You can use `<slot>` as a workaround, but I think there might be some performance issues.

Comment: I'm completely new to this stencil, what i'm working on is that I have to build web component in stencil which has an npm dropdown (can use any dropdown but it should have multi-select option) and integrating it with angular project. Can u suggest me a solution for this

Comment: Well, you can use any library that works with vanilla js, for example: https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices.

Answer (score 1):

Though I wouldn't recommend it, it's possible to use react components inside Stencil, by including the react runtime in your component (yeah sounds pretty ineffective).

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62046928/2897426. It's for using a `react-bootstrap` component which is fairly similar. Note that Stencil's JSX (or really TSX) is not compatible with React's JSX, thus you can't use JSX to pass the properties. It'll be something like

```js
import { Component, h, State } from '@stencil/core';
import { Multiselect } from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

@Component({
    tag: 'ui-card',
    styleUrl: 'style.scss',
    shadow: true
})
export class UiCard {
  @Element() host: HTMLUiCardElement;

  @State() state: any;

  @Watch('state')
  onStateChange() {
    const props = {
      options: this.state.options,
      // ...
    };

    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Multiselect, props), this.host);
  }

  componentWillLoad() {
    this.onStateChange();
  }

  render() {
    return <Host />;
  }
}
```

Again, I don't recommend doing this, it'll completely bloat your component with the whole react runtime. Just saying it's possible.

Comment: Actually I have an stencil project with many components which has a multiple select dropdown too, I have to create this web component and integrate it with Angular project. Is there any reference for that or will this work angular also

Comment: Integrating Stencil web components into Angular is pretty straight-forward, there's also pretty extensive docs for it: https://stenciljs.com/docs/angular (plus the Ionic source code). Please don't ask me about interoperability issues when wrapping a react component in a stencil component that you then use in an angular project. It sounds like a stupid plan, rather just pick a framework 

Comment: Yh. I understand it sounds weird but, is there any way I can add an npm package or ngx package to stencil project which can be integrated to Angular. Because I am starting with project for which we create web components and integrate to angular, So I want to know whether npm or npx package is supported in stencil for dropdowns and all or will I have to write a custom code for it